# Is it possible to display google web app html page before authenticating ?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to display my google wep app html page first then with the help of button i want to authenticate the user. Is it possible ? Please help on this.

Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible unless you write two webapps. One without login which shows a link to the 2nd webapp.
Or make a google site with a public page that links to a private page.